# Number of different ways in choosing balls

Tags: combinatorics

A box contains 20 red balls, 30 blue balls, and 25 green balls. How many different combinations of three colors can be made if 40 balls are picked up from the box?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried some problems which are similar to this. E.g: https://www.quora.com/A-bag-has-6-blue-balls-8-red-balls-5-black-balls-9-white-balls-How-do-you-pick-balls-from-the-bag-without-seeing-as-to-be-sure-that-3-balls-of-them-are-of-the-same-color

Comment: Are the balls identical in all ways except possibly color?  Does order of colors as you pull them out matter?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'probability'?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for the number of integer solutions to the system: $\begin{cases}r+b+g=40\\0\leq r\leq 20\\0\leq b\leq 30\\0\leq g\leq 25\end{cases}$.  To answer this, apply stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion.  Thankfully, inclusion-exclusion will go by very quickly with very little work since it is impossible to violate multiple upperbound conditions simultaneously.

Comment: @JMoravitz Let me try this method then. Thanks

Comment: The comment of @JMoravitz touches on a subtlety: whether, for a given problem [stars and bars + inclusion-exclusion] is better or [generating functions] is better.  For a contrast between the two, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876263/find-the-number-of-triples-k-1-k-2-k-3-of-integers-such-that.